# Mongoimport switch to active member of replica set

Tags: mongodb, replication, replicaset, mongoimport

I am trying to set mongoimport to connect to replica set and when i shutdown the main server during the import it switches to secondary (which is immediately set as primary by arbiter)

As for now I got this:

> mongoimport -d Patenty -c duza --file /OSTATECZNABAZA.csv --type csv --headerline  --host pierogi/147.XXX.XXX.203:27017,145.XXX.XXX.1:27017*

And its sending the file correctly but when I shut down the main server I get this error:

> 2018-08-08T13:17:24.656+0200    Failed: lost connection to server
>   2018-08-08T13:17:24.657+0200    imported 93000 documents

Is it possible by just using mongoimport to make him switch to another server in replica set ?
:)

Answer (score 0):

It might be happening because you are trying to import all the files at once, and shutting off the primary node in the middle of the import.

You can try `mongoimport option -j`.

your command looks like below

```
mongoimport -d Patenty -c duza -j 4 --file /OSTATECZNABAZA.csv --type csv --headerline --host pierogi/147.XXX.XXX.203:27017,145.XXX.XXX.1:27017*`
```

You can bump the j value and it can have values like 4, 8, 16, ... Be careful, too many concurrent imports will load the processor and make it slow.

You can also break the file and load it in pieces.